# Why not use as.integer to check if a number is an integer?

Tags: r, integer

R's `is.integer` notoriously does not check if the input is a whole number. Instead, it checks for integer typing. Its [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/integer) suggests that if we want to check if something is a whole number, we should use:

```
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
```

but wouldn't

```
is.int<-function(numb) is.numeric(numb)&&as.integer(numb)==numb
```

be a cleaner method and require one less parameter? What is the advantage of `is.wholenumber` over `is.int`?

Comment: Depending on **why** you are looking for integers, you might want to have your code use `bigz` and `bigq` from the package `gmp` .  That's life in the world of  machine-precision limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method isn't entirely dependable.

```
> sqrt(999)^2
[1] 999
> is.wholenumber(sqrt(999)^2)
[1] TRUE
> is.int(sqrt(999)^2)
[1] FALSE
> options(digits =22)
> sqrt(999)^2
[1] 998.99999999999989
```

If an operation that should return an integer goes through a process where it's slightly off then your method will say not an integer. Maybe that's what you want. But most people are looking for "is this reasonable to assume that this is an integer"